# Google Cloud Authorization Setup Showing Error - Access blocked: App’s request is invalid

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use some Google APIs Which require this OAuth Setup. i did all the necessary steps like Enabling API, OAuthConsent Screen and Credential Setup. But while trying to authenticate I am getting this error, Any Input is appreciable.
[image]

I have tried with both Published and test version of the App created in Google CLoud.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, The error 400 can be caused by different factors. Make sure all your configurations are in place. If you have a redirect URL, make sure it’s also verified in the console as it may be an issue why it’s not pushing through.Try a simple step like clearing browser cookies as it may help. In case you have other errors aside from what is presented, you may check this documentation in handling different errors related to OAuth.[1]

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#handlingerrors